# Sum of reciprocals of prime factors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

What is the value of following sum?

$$\sum_{n_1,n_2,n_3 =0} ^ \infty \frac{1}{2^{n_{1}} 3^{n_{2}} 5^{n_{3}} } $$

Where $n_1,n_2,n_3$ are positive integers.

Comment: I don't understand the notation, could you please expand the sum?

Comment: It is $\frac{1}{1-2^{-1}}\frac{1}{1-3^{-1}}\frac{1}{1-5^{-1}}$

Comment: $3.75{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{i,j= 0}^\infty a_ib_j = (\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i)(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j)$. Do you see why this is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write the sum as:
$$\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{n_2=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{n_3=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n_1}3^{n_2}5^{n_3}}\right)\right).$$
In the innermost sum, $2^{n_1}$ and $3^{n_2}$ are constant, so we can factor them out:
$$\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{n_2=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n_1}3^{n_2}} \left(\sum_{n_3=0}^\infty \frac{1}{5^{n_3}}\right)\right).$$
Again, $2^{n_1}$ is a constant in the middle sum, so we can factor it out:
$$\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n_1}}\left(\sum_{n_2=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{n_2}}\left(\sum_{n_3=0}^\infty \frac{1}{5^{n_3}}\right)\right).$$
Now whatever $\sum_{n_3}^\infty \frac{1}{5^{n_3}}$ is (you can work it out using the formula for the sum of a geometric series), it is constant with respect to $n_1$ and $n_2$, so it can be factored out:
$$\left(\sum_{n_3=0}^\infty \frac{1}{5^{n_3}}\right)\left(\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n_1}} \left(\sum_{n_2=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{n_2}}\right)\right).$$
Similarly, whatever $\sum_{n_2=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{n_2}}$ is, it is constant with respect to $n_1$ and can be factored out of the sum:
$$\left(\sum_{n_3=0}^\infty \frac{1}{5^{n_3}}\right)\left(\sum_{n_2=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{n_2}}\right)\left(\sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n_1}}\right).$$
Now use the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: Also note that the rearrangements are valid since all of the terms are positive.